# Using a regex to match only decimal numbers but I keep matching non-single-digit numbers

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

```
  check_dec=^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
  input=0
  
  echo "Please enter a digit: "
  read input
 
  if [[ $input =~ $check_dec ]]
  then
           echo "The value is a decimal"
  else
          echo "The value is an integer"
  fi
```

I am trying to store a regex in the variable "check_dec" to validate the users input.
I am having trouble understanding why any non-single-digit value I enter enters the "if" statement and reads "The value is a decimal"

As an example, when I type (44, 100, 1000, etc.), the output is "The value is a decimal"
However, when I enter a single digit number the output reads "The value is an integer"

I'm brand new to regex/bash and don't fully understand .
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your regex looks good.. what is the =~ operator

Comment: `+` means that the character before it must occur at least once. Without a trailing `$` in your regex, `1a` is also possible. See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thank you Prakhar/Cyrus for your responses...@PrakharLondhe, as far as I know the "=~" means that whatever is on the left hand sign of the operator will be matched with the regular expression on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
check_dec=^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
```

Has 2 main problems:

1. No quoting thus effectively making it `"=^[0-9]*.+[0-9]+"`. Note that in regex dot matches any character hence this (incorrect) regex means:

- Match 0 or more digits i.e. `[0-9]*`
- Match 1+ of any character i.e. `.+`
- Match 1+ of digits `[0-9]+`

So clearly this regex will require **at least 2 characters** in input and it should end with digits

2. As evident from previous comment that other than quoting issue regex itself is not correct.

Correct regex to match decimal numbers like `123.45` would be:

```
check_dec='^[0-9]*\.[0-9]+'
```

Note no quantifier `+` after dot allowing only one dot in number and quotes around.

Comment: Thank you for your comment anubhava, I found it very useful! Other than understanding that I was matching the literal "." and looking for any character, I also see that by matching for "\.+" I would allow matches for something like "....4" which wouldn't be necessary. Thank you for the response again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `\` either by:

```
check_dec=^[0-9]*\\.+[0-9]+
```

or by:

```
check_dec='^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+'
```

The reason is the `\` character has special meaning in bash:

```
$ echo ^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
^[0-9]*.+[0-9]+               <---- note: missing \
$ echo ^[0-9]*\\.+[0-9]+
^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
$ echo '^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+'
^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I used the backslash and it worked the way I expected!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with setting your regex, one is biting you now, the other ones could bite you later. You do a

```
check_dec=^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+
```

If you had done an

```
echo $check_dec
```

afterwards, you would have seen that `check_dec` contains the string *^[0-9]*.+[0-9]+* instead of *^[0-9]*\.+[0-9]+* .... The reason is that bash interprets the `\` as an (unnecessary) attempt to escape the following character.

bash also tries to interpret your `*` and `[...]` as bash wildcards for expansion. If you by chance had a file named `^7xxx.+8+`  in your working directory, `check_dec` would contain this filename instead of your carefully crafted pattern.

You need to quote the regexp to ensure that bash keeps its fingers from it:

```
check_dec='^[0-9]*[.]+[0-9]+'
```

What still is odd, is that you seem to allow more than one decimal point. For instance, the string `......22` would qualify as a decimal according to your pattern, while the string `foo_bar` would be an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I can definitely see the importance of single quotes now. I understand why "......22" would get matched (b/c my current regex is matching for one or more [.]) but I am having trouble understanding why the string foo_bar would become an integer. I didn't think to enter a string, but as you said, strings seem to return as integers.

Comment: You have only two choices: _decimal_ and _integer_. Since "foo_bar" does not match the _decimal_ pattern, control flow will end up in the _integer_ branch. It's like you have to offer either wine or beer to your guest, and you ask him: Do you want wine? If he says yes, you give him wine, else you give him beer. If he does not say "yes" (because he is muslim), you will end up giving him beer.....